# I need help fixing an "Unexpected EOF error while parsing", please

Tags: python, parsing, python-3.x, eof

I'm a first year computer science major with little clue about what I am doing, and I really need some help. I'm writing a program for an assignment that will run a simulation where the user picks 1 out of three stocks, and the program will calculate gains/losses, for 10 years.

Right now, i'm trying to implement the random section of the gains and losses and I keep running into unexpected eof while parsing error.

The error disappears when I delete the last 2 lines of the code.

I have searched for previous solutions to this on the website, but as I said, I'm very new to programming, and I'm not fluent enough in Python to understand the solutions posted to those questions.

```
import random


def main():
    starting_menu()
    choice_loop()

#Displays the starting menu 
def starting_menu():
    spendingCash=float(100.00)
    print("Current funds:", format(spendingCash, "0.2f"))
    print("Available investments")
    print("(1)Fly-By-Night investments (SCAMU): high risk, high potential returns")
    print("(2)Blue Chips INC (BCI): moderate risk, good yearly returns")
    print("(3)Slow and Steady Corp (BORE): mature industry, no risk but low returns")
    print("\nPlease enter a value from 1-3 only")
    print()

#Loop for if user selects a stock numbered other than 1-3
def choice_loop():
    chosen_stock=int(input("Stock Selection: "))

    while chosen_stock>3 or chosen_stock<1:
        print("Invalid choice, please enter number from 1-3 only")
        chosen_stock=int(input("Stock Selection: "))

    invest_chance=random.randrange(1,101)
    if chosen_stock==1:
        if invest_chance>=1 and invest_chance<=45:
```

I appreciate the help.

Comment: Please post the full stack trace from the error - it contains useful information for debugging.

Comment: Also, what version of python are you using?

Comment: just a sidenote, in choice_loop() change `int(input(''))` to `int(raw_input())`

Comment: I am using Python 3.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting that error because right now you have two if-statements at the bottom of your current program, without a "body" for the what should happen if the conditions of those statements are met.

Python expects something after the if-statements, hence it encounters the EOF (end-of-file) when it parses your code.

What, if anything, did you have there before?

When you say the error goes away, do you mean if you delete those last two lines with the if-statement? That would make sense for the reasons stated above.

Comment: Looking back on this, I'm astounded at what a simple error I make. Programming is so frustrating at times because the tiniest errors that you wouldn't think are errors can end up causing massive problems.